# Enter key prints ^M in certain situations in iTerm

Tags: macos, terminal, git, zsh, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 on a Macbook Pro running MacOS Mojave.

In certain situations, such as when doing a `git add -p`, pressing <kbd>return</kbd> ends up printing `^M` instead of performing the action.

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,j,J,g,/,e,?]? ^M
```

[image: Actual demo output]

That means I am unable to take any action on a hunk as I cannot submit any of the given choices.

---

I though this could be because of how git handles returns, so I modified the `core.autocrlf` config but none of its valid values cause any change in this behaviour.

Then when trying other methods I relaized that this problem is visible only when using **`iTerm`** and NOT the `Terminal` app despite using `zsh` in both.

---

What configuration should I modify to allow for the return key to behave normally in this case?

Comment: By any chance... do you press accidentally `CTRL+V` before hitting the `ENTER` key? In the standard zsh keybindings `CTRL+V` (`^V`) this is bound to `quoted-insert`, i.e. the next pressed key is inserted literally. `^M` for `ENTER`, `^[` for `ESC` and so on.

Comment: @mpy Did not know about that. Tried carefully again, same behaviour observed

Answer (score 35):

This problem occurs because of the odd or old terminal line settings. The `stty` tool on Unix can help you reset them.

I have had the same issue on `Iterm2` on `Mac` and got it fixed using it.

`stty sane`

This command fixes terminal oddities by resetting them to reasonable defaults.

Look at `man stty` or this good read for more info. http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=659655&seqNum=13

Comment: Just had this using standard `ssh user@host` and the `stty sane` worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

I restarted iterm tab and it got fixed.